# Does Kinesis Streams have a routing concept?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Is there something in Kinesis similar to Kafka topics to route different messages on a single endpoint? Let's say I receive the following messages

```
{
  machine: 353e62ad-255e-44d0-85df-768093bffacd
  origin: AWS 
  payload: ...
},
{
  machine: 870f9e41-d033-466d-a0db-bad04db9303d
  origin: AZURE
  payload: ...
},
{
  machine: 353e62ad-255e-44d0-85df-768093bffacd
  origin: AWS 
  payload: ...
},
{
  machine: f0c88d1d-dd73-40a6-b84e-91dd34328a46
  origin: GCP
  payload: ...
}
```

I now want to use different kinesis streams has a high volume FIFO queue for worker pools talking with AWS, GCP and Azure REST APIs. Parition key on machine for FIFO order since payloads should be delivered in-order.

Is there something that would route on kinesis level while maintaining FIFO?

- SNS FIFO limit is too low, there are 1000 req/sec/origin.

Answer (score 0):

> use different kinesis streams has a high volume FIFO queue

Use statistics, detect *Partion key* what has high volumn. Then use `PutRecord` command for create a new stream.

For what called "routing", use *partion key* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/key-concepts.html#partition-key

> Is there something that would route on kinesis level while maintaining FIFO? SNS FIFO limit is too low, there are 1000 req/sec/origin.

You can config rate limit by parameter `CollectionMaxCount` . Reference document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-producer-adv-retries-rate-limiting.html .